# What does GCC's Compare-And-Swap Guarantee on a Modern Processor

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I would like to know what __sync_bool_compare_and_swap() guarantees in different scenarios

When only one thread accesses the data - I assume it would check the pointer, and swap it if it matches the value

But what if, Two processors, compare-and-swapped at the same time? What would happen?

What if a thread compare-and-swapped when another thread was setting the value?

What if a thread compare-and-swapped when a value is protected by a mutex

Assuming of course that there are only 2 threads that access any data concurrently...

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html The whole idea of these primitives is that there's a memory barrier around each so multiple threads will get consistent results. They're e.g. used to implement spin locks.

Comment: Two things can happen: Either the operation succeeds, or it fails.

Comment: @KerrekSB so there cannot be any intermediate values between comparing and setting and the processor GUARANTEES THAT?

Comment: Success means that the original value was equal to the one you provided, and that the new value is now the one you requested. Failure means that the original value was different from the one you provided. Exactly one of those two cases happen.

Comment: @whiteclaws: yes, that's the whole point.

Comment: @kerreksb: "now" is potentially misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The key point to understand is that this is done using specific CPU instructions that are able to write atomically.

If two threads compared and swapped, one of them will be able to do it first, the other will fail and will have to retry with the new value.

If the value is protected by mutex in both threads (assuming 2 threads), then anyway `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap()` would get called one at a time. If it was protected in only one thread, consider it as if it is not protected, i.e. mutex has no effect.